# Why does dividing zero by a negative number result in negative zero?

Tags: python, rounding

I have tried to divide zero by a negative number and the result was negative zero... How do I solve that problem? Thank you...

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehyJO.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0OJp.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ylYf.png)

I would like the number zero to not have a negative sign...

Comment: Well even -0.0 isn't technically wrong mathematically because 0 is the only number that is neither positive nor negative.

Comment: You might want to do something like this `ans = str(0/-6)`
`print(ans.replace('-',''))` to get rid of the -. But yeah, it isn't wrong mathematically because 0 is not a positive number either.

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly.
Text allows for quick copy and pictures do not.
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

Since Python 3.11, the [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) allows a `'z'` option to normalize a negative zero to a positive one. You can refer to [PEP-682](https://peps.python.org/pep-0682/) for more details.

> The `'z'` option coerces negative zero floating-point values to positive
> zero after rounding to the format precision. This option is only valid
> for floating-point presentation types.

So you can format the variable with the `'z'` option, and then convert it back to a float:

```
x = -0.
print(x)
print(float(f'{x:z}'))
```

This outputs:

```
-0.0
0.0
```

Demo [here](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY31SsUbBV0DfS4Cooy80o0KjShjLSc_EQgqV5dYVVVq66pCVEO1QXTDQA)

Answer (score 0):

Since `-0.0 == 0` evaluates to `True`, which is really a positive `1` in Python, you can use [`math.copysign`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.copysign) with the sign argument being a test of whether the given number equal `0`, before defaulting to the number's own sign:

```
import math

def normalize_zero(x):
    return math.copysign(x, x == 0 or x)
```

so that:

```
print(normalize_zero(0.0))
print(normalize_zero(-0.0))
print(normalize_zero(-1.0))
print(normalize_zero(1.0))
```

outputs:

```
0.0
0.0
-1.0
1.0
```

Demo [here](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3d2fmFuQXlSjkJpZkcHGlpKYp5OUX5SbmZFalxlelFuVrVGhacSkAQVFqSWlRHlidXnJ-QWVxZnqeRoWOQoWCra2CgUJ-kUKFJhdXQVFmXokGmhEGegaamtildPHJGeKWA0tBvAD1CcxHAA)